# How to play action

Tags: animation

How do I play an action in blender?

The only solution I found is to go to "Dope Sheet" -> "Action Editor", select an action and click "Play Animation". But it plays the same action regardless of my choice.

Comment: Please elaborate it's not very clear what you are asking. Edit your question and post some more information about what you are trying to do. Possibly add some screenshots

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos is it clear now?